# gganimate::shadow_mark(): exlude all layers but 1st one

Tags: r, gganimate

I want to use shadow_mark() to leave just the 1st set of raw data remaining on the plot
to show the initial conditions. I do:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gganimate)

table(airquality$Month)

ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Month), size = 1) +
  transition_time(Month) +
  shadow_mark(colour = 'black', size = 0.75, exclude_layer = 6:9)
```

Unfortunately, the exclude_layer option does not have any effect. Am I doing something wrong or this is bug? I suspect I might not have a correct understanding of "layer".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exclude_layers` argument is used to exclude `geom` layers, i.e. in your case you have one `geom_line` and hence one layer.

I don't know whether `gganimate` offers an option to achieve your desired result but my reading of the docs is that at least for `shadow_mark` there isn't.

But a workaround would be to add your "reference" line using a second `geom_line`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) +
  geom_line(data = ~subset(.x, Month == min(Month), -Month), size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Month), size = 1) +
  transition_time(Month)
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]